# Using a full-sized image background... fixed elements to the resized image?

Tags: jquery, html, css, background

I'm planning on using a full-sized image background for a client's homepage that will stretch from edge to edge no matter what the window is resized to by using CSS or perhaps the jQuery Supersized plugin.

My question is: is there a way to fix certain elements (in this case links) to the background image instead of the browser window so that no matter what the size of the window is, I can have the links where I want them to appear relative to the image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css to loop a background image with

```
background: url(???) repeat-x;
```

You can do a vertical image of 1px size of width and repeat it, then place another background image in the center with the desired output, this way, there will be no image quality loss

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make myself clear... I've already found a way to make the full-sized image background (I'm going to use this example: http://www.alistapart.com/d/supersize-that-background-please/index3.html).

I'm trying to figure out how to fix the elements on top of it relative to the image, not the window.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but CSS z-index property will allow you to change the stack order.